# Embedded website showing in msteams webapp but not desktop app

Tags: iframe, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am building a custom ms teams application with tab capability. And I am embedding a work website inside the tab. The website loads fine in the web app. However it doesn't show in the desktop app. There is one hack to it though. If I switch to developer mode on the desktop app, it is loading the website. My website is SSO enabled for login, so it is redirecting to Idp site. One thing I have understood is, the Idp site doesn't allow their content to be loaded in an iframe, and ms teams uses iframe to load webcontent. But then I am wondering what is different for a developer mode. Why does it work there? Also since it works fine in the browser app, shouldn't it work in desktop app too. I mean the behaviour should be consistent. Any pointers?

Comment: Check the devtools console. I bet there is an error describing the issue (and also describing that it renders the iframe regardless during developer mode).

Comment: DevTools console says 'Refused to display https://login.microsoftonline.com/...... in a frame due to 'X-Frame-Options' being set to 'deny'. I understand that this is a security measure implemented by all the Idp providers to prevent from clickjacking. But then I am trying to understand how it works in developer preview. And it works with the web app version of MS teams too. The behaviour is not consistent.

Answer (score 0):

could you please follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-tab) document and you need to use microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate() to show the popup.